# Is there a better way to achieve increment and decrement?

Tags: jquery

I am doing an animation for which I need to move my div by 25px. Once the div reached 25px it should flip back to 0px, it should not stop any way. For that, I need a function to loop the div. This is what I have so far:

```
    var x = 0;
    var condition = true;

    var loopIt = function (){
        while(x < 25 && condition == true){
            x++;
            console.log(x);
            if(x == 25){
                condition = false;
            }
        }   

        while(x > 0 && condition == false){
            x--;
            if(x == 0){
                condition = true;
            }
            console.log(x);
        }
        setTimeout(loopIt, 1000);
    }

    loopIt();
```

It is working good, but i feel this is ugly. Is there any shorter way to archive the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EPmLU/1/

```
function animateDiv() {
    $('div').animate({
        left: '+=25'  // animate left 25
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('div').css('left', '-=25');  // reset animated div to orig position
        animateDiv();
    });
}

animateDiv();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
function endless(){
    $("#div").animate({
        left:'+=25px',
    }, 500, function() {
        $("#div").animate({
            left:'-=25px',
        }, 500, function() {
            endless();
        });
    });
};
endless();
```

And here the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79y2j/